# Iterating over floats written inside a string C#

Tags: c#, string, list

I read from a device a trace of floats which is saved into a string.

For example:

```
string myTrace = myDevice.ReadTrace();
```

`myTrace` after reading contains: "-54 7 6.3 70 -90..."

Then number of values inside the trace is unknown.

How can I convert the string into a `List<float>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

split based on `' '` and then map from `string` to `float` and finally collect to a list:

```
List<float> floats = myTrace.Split(' ').Select(float.Parse).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on spaces and then iterate over the collection

```
        var myTraceFloats = new System.Collections.Generic.List<float>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myTrace))
        {

            foreach (var item in myTrace.Split(' '))
            {
                float floatItem;
                if (float.TryParse(item, out floatItem))
                {
                    myTraceFloats.Add(floatItem);
                }
            }
        }
```